# .htaccess rewrite image file to php script -> show a broken image link

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is what I have for now

### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example.com/.$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$  /getAccess.php?image=$1 [NC,F,L]
```

### /getAccess.php

```
<?php
$result = $_GET['image'];
?>
<img src="<?php echo $result; ?>.jpg">
```

When I try to reach:

```
http://www.example.com/10.jpg
```

it shows me no access 403, that is good. But my problem is when I try to reach:

```
http://www.example.com/getAccess.php?image=10
```

I've tried to load the image via the PHP file but it shows me a broken image link.

Comment: Yes, the file exist.. before the .htaccess everything did work, I think the .htaccess file is my problem

Comment: What I'm trying to do is block direct access to the image file. And try to show the image only via the php file

Comment: I don't have a HTML file, all I want to do is getting the image via the php file, to make an iOS app to download it.

Comment: Yes, the php generate a HTML file, but getAccess.php is the only file that need to work

Comment: What should I do to get access via the php file, and block other direct access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example.com/.$ [NC]
> RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$  /getAccess.php?image=$1 [NC,F,L]
> ```

This doesn't rewrite the image to a PHP script (as your title suggests), it simply blocks access (which is the 403 you are seeing). However, this doesn't block "direct access" as you appear to suggest? By "direct access", we mean *typing the URL directly into the browsers address bar* - at which time the HTTP Referer is empty and your directive is not processed (excluded by the first condition). It would block a direct link from an external site (providing the HTTP Referer is passed), but controlling access based on the HTTP Referer is unreliable at best.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example.com/.$ [NC]
> ```

To fix your immediate problem, you can try removing the `.$` from the end of the above *CondPattern*. Since this will block all internal Referers that are not a single character (which is everything).

---

To block access to your image files, you would change the `RewriteRule` directive to:

```
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F]
```

This is effectively the same as what you posted. In your directive, the `/getAccess.php?image=$1` part (ie. the *substitution*) is simply being ignored - this is what the `F` flag does. In this case, you should just use a hyphen for the *substitution*.

On the other hand, to *rewrite* the request for image files to the `/getAccess.php` script, you would need to do something like the following (although this will naturally conflict with the above directive that "forbids" such a request):

```
RewriteRule (.+)\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)$  /getAccess.php?image=$1 [NC,L]
```

In your original directive, the `$1` was a backreference to just the file extension (ie. "jpg", "jpeg", "png", etc.) which would not seem to be the intention.